# Desabilitar link paginação se já estiver na página correspondente

Tags: php

tenho o código abaixo e queria adicionar a classe `disabled` quando o usuário estiver na página em que ele clicou. Por ex: se o usuário clicar na página 3 o link da página 3 teria a classe `disabled` para que não seja possível clicar nela.

```
Se for a página inicial da consulta, a variável $pag será nula

if(!$pag) {
                        $pc = "1";
                        }
                        Caso contrário, declaramos o valor atual da variável $pag
                        else {
                        $pc = $pag;
                        }
#Armazenamos a quantidade total de registros
                        $todos = $totalreg->num_rows;

                        Armazenamos o resultado da quantidade total de registros pela quantidade de registros por página
                        $tp = $todos / $registros_pagina;

E por fim montamos os links da paginação
                $tp = ceil($tp);
                if($pc>1) {
                    $anterior = $pc - 1;
                    echo '<li><a href="?pag='.$anterior.'" title="Anterior"><i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i></a></li>';
                }
                for($i=$pc-5;$i<$pc;$i++) {
                    if($i<=0) {
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<li><a href="?pag='.$i.'">';
                        if($i==$pc) {
                            echo $i;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo $i;
                        }
                        echo '</a></li> ';
                    }
                }
                for($i=$pc;$i<=$pc+5;$i++) {
                    if($i==$tp) {
                        echo '<li><a href="?pag='.$i.'">';
                        if($i==$pc) {
                            echo $i;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo $i;
                        }
                        echo '</a></li> ';
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<li><a href="?pag='.$i.'">';
                        if($i==$pc) {
                            echo $i;
                        }
                        else {
                            echo $i;
                        }
                        echo '</a></li> ';
                        if($i==$pc+5 && $tp>$pc+5) {
                            echo ' ... <li><a href="?pag='.$tp.'">'.$tp.'</a></li>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                if($pc<$tp) {
                    $proxima = $pc + 1;
                    echo '<li><a href="?pag='.$proxima.'" title="Pr&oacute;xima"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>';
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
for($i=$pc;$i<=$pc+5;$i++) {
    if($i==$tp) {
        echo '<li><a href="?pag='.$i;
        if($i==$pc) {
             echo '" class="disabled">'.$i; // <-- insere a classe disabled
        }
        else {
            echo '">'.$i; 
        }
        echo '</a></li> ';
        break;
    }
    else {
        echo '<li><a href="?pag='.$i;
        if($i==$pc) {
             echo '" class="disabled">'.$i; // <-- insere a classe disabled
        }
        else {
            echo '">'.$i; 
        }
        echo '</a></li> ';
        if($i==$pc+5 && $tp>$pc+5) {
            echo ' ... <li><a href="?pag='.$tp.'">'.$tp.'</a></li>';
        }
    }
}
```

Esse `for` pode ficar melhor. Repare na imagem que você tem 2 blocos repetidos usando a mesma avaliação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fica melhor colocar ele fora desta avaliação, pois ele é comum para ambos os casos, veja:

```
for($i=$pc;$i<=$pc+5;$i++) {
    // ---------------------inicio Bloco A --------------
    echo '<li><a href="?pag='.$i;
    if($i==$pc) {
        echo '" class="disable">'.$i; // <-- insere a classe
    }
    else {
        echo '">'.$i; 
    }
    echo '</a></li> ';
    // ---------------------final Bloco A --------------
    if($i==$tp) {
       break; 
    }
    if($i==$pc+5 && $tp>$pc+5) {
        echo ' ... <li><a href="?pag='.$tp.'">'.$tp.'</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Desta forma ele fica mais enxuto e mais fácil de dar manutenção.

Comment: Olá Andrei, não funcionou, não inseriu a classe. Acho que tinha q ser uma pesquisa baseada no parâmetro "pag=i" pq aí ja colocaria no local certo

Comment: @FredericoMoreira desculpe, eu usei o for errado pelo viso.

Comment: Eu tentei em todos. e não deu kkkk. Troquei todos os for na parte $i==$pc por $i==$pag e funcionou

Comment: @FredericoMoreira tente agora.

Comment: @FredericoMoreira no segundo loop

Comment: @FredericoMoreira tem algumas redundâncias neste `for` que irei tentar ajudar você a corrigir.

Comment: o que eu poderia melhorar nesse `for`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87338/discussion-between-andrei-coelho-and-frederico-moreira).

Comment: fiz isso e realmente deu uma enxugada no código. Obrigado

Comment: Legal @FredericoMoreira fiquei feliz em ajudar! Abraço!